# Fetch input values created by ngFor on button click Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular9

I have an input field which is being generated using *ngFor and I want to capture all those values inside the input field on submit button click. I have tried all possible ways but not able to get the entered data, please help me. Below is my code I have tried.

html Code:

```
arr= [{name:"test", percentage: "29"},{name:"abc", percentage: "45"}, {name:"def", percentage: "63"}]


<div *ngFor= "let obj of arr">
<input type="text" [value]="obj.percentage">
</div>
<button (click)="submit()"></button>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear at the moment. _"I want to capture all those values inside the input field"_ - what exactly do you want to do here? Do you want to access values from all the input fields inside the `submit()` event handler when the button is clicked?

Comment: I have an input field where user can enter number and I want to use that entered number and pass it to an API. So to pass it to an api I need to get the entered value details first. Hope this is clear? @MichaelD

Comment: Look into https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution does not have any sort of form manager. There are two solutions:

#### Reactive Forms

```
// component.ts
form = new FormGroup( {
  test: new FormControl(null)
  // Add your other fields here
} );

// Patch your values into the form
arr.forEach(value => {
  this.form.get(value.name).patchValue(value.percentage);
})

// html
<div *ngFor= "let obj of arr">
  <input type="text" [formControl]="form.get(obj.name)" >
</div>
```

Your form will store all the values. To get them once, you could use `form.value`

#### NgModel

```
// component.ts
test: boolean;
// Add your other fields here

// Patch your values into the form
arr.forEach(value => {
  this.[value.name] = value.percentage;
})

// html
<div *ngFor= "let obj of arr">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="obj.name" >
</div>
```

Both of these examples are cutting corners but they should give you enough of an idea of where to head next. I'd suggest the Reactive Forms path.